# NSArrayController fetch vs filter predicate

Tags: cocoa, nsarraycontroller

I'm working on a Mac app and am struggling to get a predicate filter to work.  Is there a difference in how you should use the fetch vs filter predicates for an NSArrayController?

I'm using Core Data to store my records and they display perfectly in my table view.  When I use the fetch predicate it properly displays the records.  When I use the filter predicate it does not seem to do anything.  Just to be clear - I'm using one predicate at a time but wanted to show both in my code.

```
entryController = [[NSArrayController alloc] init];
[entryController setManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
[entryController setAutomaticallyPreparesContent:YES];
[entryController setAutomaticallyRearrangesObjects:YES];
[entryController setClearsFilterPredicateOnInsertion:NO];
[entryController setEntityName:@"Entry"];

// only displays entries where deleted is not 1
[entryController setFetchPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deleted != %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]];

// shows all entries regardless of the deleted status
[entryController setFilterPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"deleted != %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:1]]];

if ([entryController fetchWithRequest:nil merge:YES error:&error] == NO) {
    DLog(@"Error fetching entries: %@", error.description);
} else {
    DLog(@"Found %lu entries.", [[entryController arrangedObjects] count]);
}
```

Comment: After you set the filter predicate do you tell the NSTableView to reload its data?

Comment: Yes I reload the view data.  I'm also positive the deleted value is 1 because 1) it works with the fetch predicate, and 2) i'm printing the value as part of the cell.

Comment: I took another look at your code. Do you realize that there is no difference between your fetch predictate and your filter predicate? They both evaluate the same.

Comment: Yes, that is what is confusing me.  It seems like either way should work unless I'm misunderstanding how filter predicates work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the keyword "deleted" has some unknown significance to Core Data.  I renamed my property and it resolved the issue.  This blog post also mentions the same issue: http://roobasoft.com/blog/2006/04/25/secret-core-data-reserved-keywords/

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand fetchPredicate is performed at the store level and filteringPredicate is performed in memory after the objects have already been retrieved.

Comment: so, does an arraycontroller without a fetch predicate but a filter predicate fetch all instances and filters those afterwards?